# What are they different among Bitmap, Canvas and drawable? why so difficulty to design such concepts?

Tags: android, bitmap

We have always confused bitmap with displayed graphic, despite we know bitmap is a graphic with pixels displaying.

as if the bitmap were only a structure, which pixels data can be presented by a byte array, i.e. bytes[].
if it will be displayed, one way is copy its data to canvas, then edit or transform and display it on it.

while drawable is a container which fill various type of graphics like bitmap, jpeg etc.

The question is why designers design so complex display system? how to reduce some joints to easy use display function?

Comment: so you say that you do not understand what is it all about but still you know that is "so complex"? it's just a matter of filling knowledge gap. not everything can be one line of code

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, I have never said I don't understand them. Im curious, from where you find that? the higher degree the language is, the simple the code will be.

Comment: I wonder who say the thread is unclear? reason, do you know these concepts very well? if you are not specialist, dont vote negatively

Comment: Warning to those who vote negatively. if you were not specialist, Do read carefully. if not, you will be condemned.

Comment: by Marcin Orlowski, Robert P., laalto, kingkero, Selvin    those are only students who have merely learned a little computer. but like to make practice joke.

Comment: looks you need to learn not only about canvas and bitmaps...

Comment: I should learn more about mirror, how to reveal those guys.

Comment: keeping talking o you is waste of time as clearly seen, but it would help you if you understand how SO works first.

Comment: pls don't waste your time. you can play anywhere on the playground. anyway there were always some guys who like to make practice joke. if you like you can down vote again. pls do.

Comment: @Robert P., laalto, kingkero, Selvin you acted as clowns as you leave no any words. but down vote.

Answer (score 3):

In short

Bitmap - is a representation of image in byte form.

Drawable - is an abstraction of anything which can be drawn. (image, gradients, circles, shape, 9 patch, state, layers etc)

Canvas - is a place, where you draw. Like real life Canvas. Where you can draw anything.

Whats so complex in graphic system? I mean in real life drawing, you've canvas, you have colors, you have brushes, and any scene and its component or smallest detail which you are going to draw is Drawable. And when you are done with your painting, that can be converted into image which can be displayed somewhere. So every canvas has a Bitmap where it'll show the drawn image.

You should really consult android developer documentation. Those nice people has document it already for you [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) and [Canvas and Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)

Comment: I know this web site and read some articles about it. you don't copy their words which I know very much. do read my thread, what I want to know why they design so complex?

Comment: @learner1 :) boy! what would you do to draw an image in real life?  If this design looks complex to you, you might want to propose your own simple easy solution. What I mean is, **this** is the same discipline in which you would draw a real life image. Isn't it?

Comment: if you were one of the negative voter. do remember you are not welcome to answer my question. you are only a copier.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Can you tell me what part I did copy? Btw, you've entered into a community, and anyone can downvote if they think your question or answer doesn't conform the community posting rules.

Comment: you are not down vote one. your words were really copied which I can read in any article. this is a serious forum web site, but there are still some guys who like to make practice joke. they have little computer knowledge, but like to down vote. they must be teenages.

Comment: I copy some, too. The Canvas class holds the "draw" calls. To draw something, you need 4 basic components: A Bitmap to hold the pixels, a Canvas to host the draw calls (writing into the bitmap), a drawing primitive (e.g. Rect, Path, text, Bitmap), and a paint (to describe the colors and styles for the drawing). Here it is, writing into the bitmap or writing bitmap onto canvas? the last I prefer to.